# Queue with search ability and receiving at specific time

Tags: events, rabbitmq, queue

I need to send some DTO's (events) to queue. Event can be handled now or in the future (defines by eventTime filed in DTO which is Timestamp (LocalDateTime)).

I am looking for queue with ability to:

- search events in queue (e.g get all events with DateTime > NOW() && eventType= 'ACTIVE') without taking event from queue.
- manage requeue of events or recive time

In our company we use RabbitMQ only for events that have to execute now (without evens in the future). I was reading about RabbitMQ and I found that I can reject messages (and then message is requeue) but I found nothing about searching through queue without taking message from it. Is it possible in RabbitMQ to do that ? Or what queue / tool should I use ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible in RabbitMQ to do that ? Or what queue / tool should I use ?

It is not possible. You would have to consume all messages to search for the one(s) you need, and then reject / requeue others.